# Setting onClickListner for items within popup window in android

Tags: android, onclick, android-popupwindow

I have a popup window that contains 2 text views.

If user click on one text view toast must appear.I coded for this function but shows `Nullpointer exception` in line `far.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {` Please help me on this.

My code :

```
btn_a.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            LayoutInflater lInflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View popup_view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_a, null);
            final PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(popup_view,200,75,true);
            popup.setFocusable(true);
            popup.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable());   
            popup.showAsDropDown(btn_a,  0,0);

            TextView far = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fartext);
            far.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Clicked Far", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change this line

```
TextView far = (TextView) popup_view.findViewById(R.id.fartext);
```

instead of this

```
TextView far = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fartext);
```

Comment: always wc @tenten.

Answer (score 3):

You get a `NullPointerException` because you are trying to set a click listener on a view that is actually part of your popup_view and not rootView. Fix it like this:

```
TextView far = (TextView) popup_view.findViewById(R.id.fartext);
            far.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Clicked Far", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is your are looking in `rootView` where `fareText` is not exists. You should look into the inflated layout. Check below code.

```
btn_a.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        LayoutInflater lInflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View popup_view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_a, null);
        final PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(popup_view,200,75,true);
        popup.setFocusable(true);
        popup.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable());   
        popup.showAsDropDown(btn_a,  0,0);

        TextView far = (TextView) popup_view.findViewById(R.id.fartext);
        far.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Clicked Far", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
    }
});
```